# On all pages dynamic @yield does not show anything. How do I share data between all pages?

Tags: php, laravel

On all internal pages, except for the **layouts/app.blade.php**, these blocks are empty. Why?

```
<li>
    @yield('fresh_comments')
    @yield('news_month')
    @yield('news_random')
</li>
```

Comment: Can you show one of your other files for comparison?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9CxKtBKf

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your app.blade.php does not contain

```
   @section('fresh_comments')
   @end
```

Can you ether paste your complete 'app.blade.php' or the fragment where you include '@section('fresh_comments')'?

Edit :

```
@extends('layouts/app.blade.php')
```

should be

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the blade.php name in your extends, just the path and the name in dot-syntax, like so:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```